# GCP Removed Access To Google Collab User

Tags: google-cloud-platform, aws-secrets-manager, google-secret-manager

I used to be able to use secretmanager to get secrets from my GCP account using google collab.

Now, whenever I try to run the following code:

```
client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
name = f"projects/my_project_here/secrets/my_secret_name_here/versions/latest"
response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": name})
```

I get the following error over and over:

```
ERROR:grpc._plugin_wrapping:AuthMetadataPluginCallback "<google.auth.transport.grpc.AuthMetadataPlugin object at 0x7fb313b41850>" raised exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 111, in refresh
    self._retrieve_info(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 88, in _retrieve_info
    request, service_account=self._service_account_email
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 234, in get_service_account_info
    return get(request, path, params={"recursive": "true"})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 187, in get
    response,
google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb''", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7fb313b9c290>)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py", line 90, in __call__
    context, _AuthMetadataPluginCallback(callback_state, callback))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 101, in __call__
    callback(self._get_authorization_headers(context), None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 88, in _get_authorization_headers
    self._request, context.method_name, context.service_url, headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 117, in refresh
    six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb''", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7fb313b9c290>)
```

How can I see what user I am in google collab and then add this user in GCP so I can again fetch these secrets?

I know to go to GCP->Secret Manager->My_Secret->Permissions->+Grant Access, but I don't know how to know 1) Who to Add 2) Why this permission changed on its own with no intervention on anyone's end.

Both were originally running under my email (and they are still) so this worked without me ever having to touch secrets access because both were the App Engine default service account<->Secret Manager Secret Accessor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing GCP Secrets Manager from Google Colab notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76518802/accessing-gcp-secrets-manager-from-google-colab-notebook)