# Accessing GCP Secrets Manager from Google Colab notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

How can I access a secret in GCP Secrets Manager from a Google Colab notebook ?
I have already setup the secret in Secrets Manager

I have code that looks like this:

```
 client=secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
 secret_name="some_api_key"
 project_id="XXXXXXXXXYYYYY"
 resource_name=f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_name}"
 print(resource_name)
 # Get secret
 response=client.access_secret_version(request={"name":resource_name})
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:grpc._plugin_wrapping:AuthMetadataPluginCallback " 
<google.auth.transport.grpc.AuthMetadataPlugin object at 0x7f54f90373a0>" raised 
exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist- 
packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 111, in refresh
self._retrieve_info(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist- 
packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 87, in _retrieve_info
info = _metadata.get_service_account_info(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist- 
packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 234, in 
get_service_account_info
return get(request, path, params={"recursive": "true"})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist- 
packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 182, in get
raise exceptions.TransportError(
google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: ("Failed to retrieve 
http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. 
Status: 404 Response:\nb''", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7f54f9022110>)
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how Colab works, but your error means there is not a metadata server that provide identity to the Client Library and therefore, the API call can't be done with a oauth token. If you can run a gcloud command on colab, can you run `gcloud auth application-default login`

Comment: It turns out that I needed to authenticate with Google Cloud. I was able to do so interactively using `from google.colab import auth` then `auth.authenticate_user()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to authenticate with Google Cloud. I was able to do so interactively as follows:

```
from google.colab import auth 
auth.authenticate_user()
```

Comment: You have saved me from madness, and are more useful than all the google documentation combined